# Getting NASM Segmentation fault(Core dumped) after running program. What is the error in the program that I have attached below?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, nasm, coredump

```
%macro print 2

        mov ecx,%1

        mov edx,%2

        mov ebx,1

        mov eax,4

int 80h

%endmacro


section .data

        m dq "Big endian number is : 1020304050607080",10

        l equ $-m

        m1 dq "Little endian number : "

        l1 equ $-m1

        number dq 1020304050607080H

        l2 equ $-number

        cntr db 8

    
section .bss

        digits resb 8

section .text

    global _start

    _start:

        print m,l

        print m1, l1

        mov rbx,0       ;final zero

        mov rax,[number]

        mov rcx,8

        mov rdi,100h

        mov rsi, digits

        mov cl, 8

next:   shl rbx,8
    
        mov rdx,00
    
        div rdi
    
        add rbx, rdx

        jmp again

        print digits, 8

        dec rcx

        jnz next

mov eax, 1

mov ebx, 0

int 80H

    again : mov al, byte[rdx]           ;get byte
        and al, 0F0H                ;mask lower nibble
        shr al, 04H
        cmp al, 0aH
        jb add_30
        add al, 37H
        jmp store

    add_30 : add al, 30H

    store : mov [rsi], al
        inc rsi
        mov al, byte[rdx]
        and al, 0FH
        cmp al, 0aH
        jb add_30h1
        add al, 37H
        jmp store1

    add_30h1 : add al, 30H

    store1 : mov [rsi], al
         inc rsi
```

I am getting this thing when I run this program (whose aim is to print number in little endian format from given big endian format) on terminal in fedora. (END is the name of my program)

> [dell@localhost MAL]$ nasm -f elf64 END.asm
>
> [dell@localhost MAL]$ ld -s -o END END.o
>
> [dell@localhost MAL]$ ./END

Big endian number is : 1020304050607080

Little endian number : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

What must be the problem?

Comment: x86 processors are little-endian, so `number dq 1020304050607080H` will give you `1020304050607080H` in a little-endian layout. And why are you using `dq` instead of `db` for character data?

Comment: What comes after the last line (`inc rsi`)?

Comment: `mov al, byte[rdx]` <-- As far as I can tell, `rdx` contains the remainder of `[number] / 100h` at that point, which won't be a valid address. You should probably sit down for a while and think about your code and what it's supposed to do, as well as stepping through it in a debugger to see what's actually happening.

Comment: @rkhb, the control should jump back to the line 6 in label 'next', which is print digits, 8

Comment: @Michael, Actually I am not that good at assembly level language, so this was just a  try to write code on my own. And I got the point that you said about dq, db. But didn't get what you wanted to say in next comment, "won't be a valid address". May I know what's going wrong there.

Comment: The remainder of `[number] / 100h` will be a value in the range 0-255. Let's say that it's 255. So now your `mov al, byte[rdx]` is trying to read a byte from address 255. What exactly were you expecting to find at that address?